# How to extract data in specified column in the pandas dataframe without index

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe called `data` of size (150, 5). Now I want to get the data in the last column whose header is "Species":

```
output_data = data["Species"]
```

The resulting `output_data` is of type `Series` including an index column. How to remove the index data or directly extract the data of the `Species` column?

Comment: data["Species"].tolist()

Answer (score 1):

you have to cast the series to list `output_data = list(data["Species"])`